# Why is Sagemaker trying to upload model again

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am facing issue with my Sagemaker model deployment. I have my model data already available in S3 and I supply that to model but it fails with access issue while uploading to s3 again:

**Error:**

> S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload
> /tmp/tmpoy3pcol_/temp-model.tar.gz to
> xyz_bucket/text_trove/model.tar.gz: An error occurred (AccessDenied)
> when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied

**Source:**

```
sess = sagemaker.Session(
    default_bucket = "xyz_bucket"
)
bucket = sess.default_bucket()

pretrained_model_data = sess.upload_data(
    path="model-tiny.tar.gz", bucket=bucket, key_prefix="abc/pqr/test/summarizer"
)

model=PyTorchModel(py_version='py3',
    name="text_trove",
    image_uri="texttrove/tt_sagemaker_py3.8_cuda11.0_torch_2.0:latest",
    entry_point="inference.py",
    source_dir=".",
    role=role,
    model_data=pretrained_model_data, sagemaker_session= sess 
)

predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer(),
    sagemaker_session=sess,  
    tags=[{"Key":"app_group","Value":"xyzzy_tag"}]
)
```

I don't access to root level of the bucket that's why it fails. I really appreciate if someone can help me understand:

1. why is it trying to upload model again when it's already available in s3?
2. How do I change S3 prefix for `model.deploy(....)` so it won't upload to root or upload to the nested accessible path?

Comment: Can you share how huge is your model in terms of file size?

Comment: its about 500MB. docker image is over 16G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing an `entry_point`, the SageMaker SDK will download the model.tar.gz from S3, re-package the tar.gz to include this script and upload it back to S3.

If you already have the model.tar.gz in S3 and the inference script is included in the tar.gz, then you don't need to set `entry_point`. Instead you can just set [`model_data`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html#pytorch-model) to the S3 location where your model.tar.gz is.

Comment: thanks. let's say if I have inference explicitly then how do I change S3 prefix to where I have access?

Comment: If you mean how can you change the prefix where the SDK uploads the new model tar.gz you can set the default_bucket_prefix in the Session https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session

Comment: are there any other alternative to change s3 prefix? I am using sagemaker  2.155.0 and this parameter isn't available-
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(
    default_bucket = "...." ,default_bucket_prefix="......"
)

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_bucket_prefix'`